# Google Maps in HTML5 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

i was getting crazy with simple HTML5 landing page. I also searched for answer here. 
The problem is that my HTML page have a contact's module at the bottom, it included to code of main page as:

```
    <!-- +++ START - Contact Right +++ -->
            <div class="ms-section" id="right5">

                <div class="map-info split-section">

                    <div id="map"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- +++ END - Contact Right +++ -->

        </div>
        <!-- CLOSE - RIGHT PART -->
```

and this:

```
    <!-- Main JS File -->
    <script src="js/main-multi-scroll.js"></script>
```

I was getted with manual and done map.js file, it listed below:

```
// When the window has finished loading create our google map below
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', init);

function init() {

// Basic options for a simple Google Map
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEYVALUE&callback=initMap">
        </script>
// The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.76197976545492,37.68354535102844);
// For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 1024 ? true : false; // If document (your website) is wider than 1024px, isDraggable = true, else isDraggable = false

// For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
var mapOptions = {
    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
    zoom: 18,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: isDraggable,
    center: center,
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,

    zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},

streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},

    // How you would like to style the map. 
    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.


     styles: [
{
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 65
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 51
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 30
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 40
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "hue": "#006bff"
        },
        {
            "lightness": "-10"
        },
        {
            "saturation": "-92"
        },
        {
            "gamma": "0.37"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#323a45"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#4f5256"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }
    ]
}
]
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions, center);

var locations = [
    ['<h6>ул. Радио, д. 24, к.1</h6><p>БЦ Яуза Тауэр<br><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> Приходите к нам в гости!</p>', 55.76197976545492,37.68354535102844, 1],
];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var image = 'img/v-logo-map.png';

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, i));
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

}
```

The problem that i've did everything by manual and google maps doesn't show on my website. I also geeted Google Maps API auth request, generated it and inserted into code, that doesn't helped me at all.

If you wanna check closer - http://vernizone.ru

Hope you can help me solve it out - i have to go with production version of this site.

Comment: How are you setting the size of the map div? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: i have made some necessary changes to your code.

remove the following `<script>` tag from map.js file and place it on the index page, before the `</body>` tag

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=init&v=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and your map.js file should be the same (just minus that above  tag)

```
   // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', init);

   function init() {

    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.76197976545492,37.68354535102844);
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 1024 ? true : false; // If document (your website) is wider than 1024px, isDraggable = true, else isDraggable = false

    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 18,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: isDraggable,
        center: center,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,

        zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },

    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },

        // How you would like to style the map. 
        // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
        styles: [
{
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 65
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 51
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 30
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 40
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "hue": "#006bff"
        },
        {
            "lightness": "-10"
        },
        {
            "saturation": "-92"
        },
        {
            "gamma": "0.37"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#323a45"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#4f5256"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }
    ]
}
]
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions, center);

    var locations = [
        ['<h6>ул. Радио, д. 24, к.1</h6><p>БЦ Яуза Тауэр<br><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> Приходите к нам в гости!</p>', 55.76197976545492,37.68354535102844, 1],
    ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var image = 'img/v-logo-map.png';

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, i));
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Heya, i've added &callback=initMap - that doesn't helped me

Comment: i was also tryed to get without this code at all as it was in example -- it doesn't work also

Comment: i have edited the answer as per the solution i found, try and tell if it helped